# Ruby: convert from MDEG to ST_Point

Tags: ruby, postgresql, geolocation, gps

I have some GPS information stored as MDEG (Millions of degrees) and I want to save it into Postgres using ST_Point.

Having it divided as a float probably will give reliability issues. Which is then the most reliable way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There obviously was a very short way to do it, thanks to [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html).
If you are working on a Rails project is already loaded, if not you must `require 'bigdecimal/util'`

After that the `#to_d` method is available, letting you work with decimals without losing precision.

```
# @param mdeg [Array<int,int>] latitude and longitude in mdeg format
# @return [String] String to build up the ST_Point
def mdeg_to_stpoint(mdeg)
  mdeg_d = mdeg.collect { |x| x.to_d / 1_000_000 }
  "Point(#{mdeg_d[0]} #{mdeg_d[1]})"
end
```